# Change language of the Terminal's output in linux

Tags: linux, locale

Is there a way to change the language of o/p returned by any command in linux?

Just take for example

```
/sbin/service cloudstack-usage status 
cloudstack-usage は停止しています
```

I want to translate the Japanese text returned.
Why i need this :- I have some in-house script which will check if the service is stopped or not and then perform activity .
And i check that by

```
/sbin/service $SERVICE_NAME status | grep stop
```

Any suggestions highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Bourne shell or its descendents, you can set the environment for a single command by prefixing it with variable assignments, e.g.,

```
LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8 /sbin/service cloudstack-usage status cloudstack-usage
```

if the program is *localized* and you wanted messages in Japanese.  To get POSIX (no translation), you would use LANG=C

There are several variables in your locale settings.  Use the [locale](http://linux.die.net/man/1/locale) command to show what they are set to.